# Can I change key bindings in Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Is there a way to change what keys are mapped to secondary scrolling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Press <kbd>esc</kbd>ape
- Select *Key Bindings*
- Select *General*
- Change the following items:

  - Move Secondary Selector Up
  - Move Secondary Selector Down
  - Page Secondary Selector Up
  - Page Secondary Selector Down

You can add a binding by selecting *Add Binding* and pressing the respective key.

You can remove a binding by selecting an already set binding and pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

In this screen you can also change the repeat rate (what happens when you hold the button.)

Answer (score 1):

Edit [interface.txt](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Key_bindings#ixzz0tVHqmxOw), changing the following entries to whatever keys you'd like:

```
[BIND:SECONDSCROLL_UP:REPEAT_SLOW]
[KEY:-]
[BIND:SECONDSCROLL_DOWN:REPEAT_SLOW]
[KEY:+]
[BIND:SECONDSCROLL_PAGEUP:REPEAT_SLOW]
[KEY:/]
[BIND:SECONDSCROLL_PAGEDOWN:REPEAT_SLOW]
[KEY:*]
```

Comment: I actually was able to find the answer to this on my own, even if its not the best answer, which is part of why I posted the question :)